# Security of modular exponentiation for non-uniform inputs

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose we have a function $F = f_{s}(x)$ with a key $s \gets \mathbb{Z}_q$ that on input $x$ outputs modular exponentiation $x^s$, where $\mathbb{G}$ is a cyclic group of order $q$ where DDH is hard. If $x$ is selected uniformly at random from $\mathbb{G}$, then modular exponentiation $F$ behaves like a weak PRF ([Naor et. al "Distributed Pseudo-Random Functions and KDCs"](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Enaor/PAPERS/npr.pdf)).

However, what happens when inputs are not chosen at random? Say, one can query $F$ for any $x \in  \mathbb{G}$. Are there any security estimations?

Comment: Hint: $(xy)^s=(x^s)(y^s)$. Or the lesser $1^s=1$.

Comment: @fgrieu Homomorphic properties? Not sure what you mean. Sure, $F$ wouldn't be weak PRF as we can't do a reduction to DDH with adaptive $x$ selection. But I'm not sure what would $F$ be.

It is not a one-way function as $x$ is not a random generator (as per this def https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs127/fall13/lec9.pdf).  Don't know. I can't find a way to show $F$ leaks $x$ eventually, nor can I prove it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when inputs are not chosen at random?

We can distinguish an oracle implementing some $f_s$ from one implementing a true PRF with near certainty, as follows:

- Take two arbitrary group elements $x$ and $y$.
- Compute $z=xy$ by multiplying in the group.
- Query the oracle with $x$, $y$, and $z$ so that we get $X=f_s(x)$, $Y=f_s(y)$, $Z=f_s(z)$.
- Test if $XY=Z$ and if so output "the oracle probably is implementing some $f_s$", else output "the oracle must be implementing a PRF".

This works because $(x^s)(y^s)=(xy)^s$.

We can simplify this by querying with $x$ and $z=x^2$ and checking $Z=X^2$. Or just by querying with $x=1$ and checking $X=1$, where $1$ is the group identity.

This contrasts with when we are limited to random queries: no such distinguisher is possible.

Comment: Yes, $F$ wouldn't be PRF, not even weak PRF (it's not a question). The question is: what security does it have? Can we prove something about $F$ when $x$ is not random?

Comment: @pintor: I see. You want some _positive_ result on some aspect of the security of $F$; like, it can't be inverted even with access to an oracle implementing $F$ (or perhaps, no past access to an oracle for $F$ will allow to compute $F$ for a random $x$). I'm clueless.

Comment: @ fgrieu Yeah, I'm clueless too. Thank you anyway.
Anyway, I realized I didn't phrase my question well (it's unclear if I'm asking for positive results or just wondering why). I'll accept the answer (it's a good one) and create another question with hopefully better wording.